# System.Linq.Dynamic.Core : How do I make a select many correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dynamic-linq

I am new to the System.Linq.Dynamic.Core. I have this:

Let's say we have:

```
Packs = new List<Pack>
{
    new Pack()
    {
        IdAtSource="Pack1",
        Equipments= new List<Equipment>()
        {
            new Equipment
            {
                Id=1,
                GenericEquipment = new GenericEquipment()
                {
                    Id=7
                }
            }
        }
    },
    new Pack()
    {
        IdAtSource="Pack2",
        Equipments= new List<Equipment>()
        {
            new Equipment
            {
                Id=2,
                GenericEquipment = new GenericEquipment()
                {
                    Id=1
                }
            },
            new Equipment
            {
                Id=2,
                GenericEquipment = new GenericEquipment()
                {
                    Id=2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to select the `Packs` with `Equipments`, but in the selected `Equipments` I need to have **only** the one with `Id=2` for Generic Equipment.(the result should contain a list of packs with list of equipments).

I've tried this:

```
querable.Where("Packs.Equipments.Select((GenericEquipment.Id)=1)");
```

but I feel I am waaay of target here. Also is there any documentation page on how to use this library?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent version of Dynamic LINQ appears to be the project [here](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core), with the documentation [here](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions).

---

Generally, the only reason why you should require Dynamic LINQ over standard LINQ is when the types are **not** known at compile time.

If you know at compile time that the query will be against a `List<Pack>`, you can use stanadard LINQ, as in the following code (note that this modifies the original instances of `Pack`):

```
var usefulPacks = Packs.Select(pack => {
    pack.Equipments = pack.Equipments.Where(equipment => 
        equipment.GenericEquipment.Id == 1
    ).ToList(); 
}).Where(pack => pack.Equipments.Any()).ToList();
```

If you need code that doesn't modify the original instances, this code creates copies of the original instances:

```
var usefulPacks = Packs.Select(pack => {
    return new Pack() {
        IDAtSource = pack.IDAtSource,
        Equipments = pack.Equipments.Where(equipment => 
            equipment.GenericEquipment.Id == 1
        ).ToList(); 
    };
}).Where(pack => pack.Equipments.Any()).ToList();
```

Note that this isn't using `.SelectMany` — `.SelectMany` is used to create a single enumerable from nested enumerables; here each `Pack` in the final list corresponds to a `Pack` in the original list.

---

Dynamic LINQ doesn't support modifying or initializing properties as part of the expression:

> The expression language permits getting (but not setting) the value of any reachable public field, property, or indexer.

so the `Equipments` property cannot be changed / initialized to include only instances of `Equipment` that match the criteria.

In order to set the `Equipments`, you have two choices:

1. Add a constructor to `Pack` which takes the appropriate arguments
2. Write a static method on any class which takes the appropriate arguments

---

**Add a constructor to `Pack`**

You can add a constructor to `Pack` with the appropriate arguments, that sets `Equipments`:

```
Pack(int IDAtSource, IEnumerable<Equipment> equipments) {
    this.IDAtSource = IDAtSource;
    this.Equipments = equipments.ToList();
}
```

Then you could use the following:

```
IQueryable qry = Packs.AsQueryable();
qry = qry
    .Select("Pack(IDAtSource, Equipments.Where(GenericEquipment.ID=1))")
    .Where("Equipments.Any");
```

---

**Define a static method**

```
public static class MyPackMethods {
    public static Pack Create(int IDAtSource, IEnumerable<Equipment> equipments) {
        return new Pack() {
            IDAtSource = IDAtSource,
            Equipments = equipments.ToList()
        };
    }
}
```

and call:

```
IQueryable qry = Packs.AsQueryable();
qry = qry
    .Select("MyPackMethods.Create(IDAtSource, Equipments.Where(GenericEquipment.ID=1))")
    .Where("Equipments.Any");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! In fact it almost answers my question. When I finish the selection, I need to have the Pack, with *just* the equipments that have GenericEqipments with Id=1. Meaning in the list of Equipments only one equipment should show up. And also, I don't know the types at runtime, it was just an easier example to give like this. Thanks again, your asnwer is very helpfull.

Comment: @Strawberry That's what is happening in the Dynamic LINQ query. First we're calling `.Select` which creates a new instance of `Pack` for each initial instance of `Pack`, but passes in only the matching `Equipment` to the constructor of the new instance: `Equipments.Where(GenericEquipment.ID=1)`; then we're calling `.Where` to include only instances of `Pack` which have something in the `Equipments` property.

Comment: Understood dear sir. But unfortunately it's not an option to change the constructor, so i can use that solution.

Answer (score 0):

These should work:

```
var equipments= from pack in Packs where pack.Equipments.Any() select pack.Equipments;

var secondEquipments = from pac in equipments where       
pac.GenericEquipment.Id == 2 select pac;
//I could use one variable instead of 2 but that would look a little bit complex
```

Msdn Link(Sorry I'm at mobile so I can't rename it):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx

Comment: Thank you kind sir! Yet this does not answer my question, on how to use the library Linq.Dynamic.Core.

Comment: No problem, but I think this answers your question. Let me correct it please :)